# What is '<eps>' in Watson speech to text output?

Tags: ibm-watson

Our Watson speech to text output includes many instances of the token `<eps>`. I cannot find any information in the service documentation describing what this is. What is it?

Comment: Incidentally, while there is a `watson-text-to-speech` tag, there appears to be no `watson-speech-to-text` tag, and I don't have high enough reputation to create one.

Comment: Please provide an example output response.